# Найти соответствия в двух таблицах, и перенести данные excel

Tags: excel

Есть два листа Excel, на одном таблица: два столбца, в одном слова, в другом цифры. На втором листе один столбец, те же слова, но в другом порядке. Задача - найти совпадения в словах, и перенести соответствующие им циферки с первого листа на второй. Буду очень благодарен за помощь, поскольку, эксель - абсолютно не мой профиль.

Comment: Данный ресурс не предназначен для решения домашних заданий. Приведите пример своего решения, и мы подскажем, в чем ваша ошибка и как ее устранить. Если же вам лень делать домашку - в интернете много бирж, где фрилансеры вам помогут. Не бесплатно, разумеется.

Answer (score 0):

На второй лист в ячейку, куда нужно подставить искомое (на картинке ниже - B1): `=ЕСЛИ(ЕНД(ВПР(A1;Лист1!$A$1:$B$7;1;0));"";ВПР(A1;Лист1!$A$1:$B$7;2;0))` и протаскиваем на весь столбец, где

- `A1` - то, что ищем (слова со второго листа);
- `Лист1!$A$1:$B$7` - диапазон где ищем (диапазон ячеек с первого листа, захватывающий и слова и цифры);
- `2` - номер столбца из диапазона поиска, из которого подставляем данные.

[image: Лист1]
[image: Лист2]

У данного метода поиска есть ряд ограничений, как то:

- Не ищет дубли с Листа1 (подставляет только первое найденное значение)
- Диапазон поиска (в данном случаи с Лист1) должен быть в таком же порядке: вначале столбец с данными по которым ищем, а затем данные, которые подставляем (при этом между ними допускаются другие столбцы)
- Возможно что-то ещё

Comment: *ЕСЛИ(ЕНД* меняем на *ЕСЛИОШИБКА* и формула почти в два раза короче (для версий после *Excel-2003*)